# Verb with no subject (well, tu but you don't say tu it's implied)

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical, impératif

How would i say verbs without a subject. Ex (in english) Do the dishes. (what verb conjugation would I use)

Comment: Welcome. Could you elaborate more please? The question is unclear, at least to me

Answer (score 4):

By conjugating the verb in the *imperative* (only possible with **tu**, **vous** and **nous**, of course).

To say "Do the dishes", you would therefore say:

> Faites la vaisselle.

or

> Fais la vaisselle.

Answer (score 3):

That would be the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#French), just as in English.

Answer (score 3):

French has an imperative, it works the same as the English one with 3 forms in the present tense instead of 1 for English:

- *fais la vaisselle* (TOI/YOU => 2sg)
- *faisons la vaisselle* (NOUS/WE => 1pl)
- *faites la vaisselle* (VOUS/YOU => 2pl)

Actually, these forms have a subject but it is not expressed outside the verb. On the other hand, infinitives do not have subjects in French or English:

- *to do the dishes is boring*
- *faire la vaisselle n'est pas amusant*